# Is "glGenBuffers" really important if we have glBindBuffer?

Tags: c++, opengl

Well, I'm starting with OpenGl, and by reading documentation about glBindBuffer, I'm a bit confused.

> "glBindBuffer binds a buffer object to the specified buffer binding point. Calling glBindBuffer with ***target*** set to one of the accepted symbolic constants and ***buffer*** set to the name of a buffer object binds that buffer object name to the target. If no buffer object with name ***buffer*** exists, one is created with that name. When a buffer object is bound to a target, the previous binding for that target is automatically broken."
>   Source: http://docs.gl/gl4/glBindBuffer

Does that mean if I don't create buffer object with "foo" name, but I call glBindBuffer, it will create one for me with that name ("foo")?

If so, following code should work fine:

```
GLuint bar = 70;
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bar);
```

-> Create buffer object, "connect" it with bar (70) and bind it to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Comment: You need to think to names as black boxes, not as integers. Suppose they are really complicated opaque values so that you want to let OpenGL generate them for you in all circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this code will work only in a compatibility profile context (or OpenGL ES).

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 2.6.1 Object Management- page 28](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> [...] the command GenBuffers returns one or more previously unused buffer object names.
>   Generated names are marked by the GL as used, for the purpose of name generation only. Object names marked in this fashion will not be returned by additional calls to generate names of the same type until the names are marked unused again by deleting them [...]

This means that `glGenBuffers` does nothing else than reserving names (values). Further calls to `glGenBuffers` will not return the same values.
If `glGenBuffers` is always used to get name values for buffer objects, then you can be sure that the value isn't already used for an other buffer object.

But in desktop OpenGL core profile specification it is not allowed to use an name for `glBindBuffer`, which wasn't reserved (returned) by `glGenBuffers`.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 6.1 Creating and Binding Buffer Objects - page 62](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> **An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if buffer is not zero or a name
>   returned from a previous call to GenBuffers**, or if such a name has since been
>   deleted with DeleteBuffers.

This part of the specification is missing in the [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification - 6.1 Creating and Binding Buffer Objects - page 62](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

That is a bit confusing, but that's the specification.

This behavior is verifiable with the code of your question. The following code  returns no error using a compatibility profile context but returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` using a core profile context:

```cpp
GLuint bar = 70;
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bar); 
GLenum error = glGetError();
```

Comment: So, to write code without using `glGenBuffers`, you would need to allocate the IDs yourself I guess? `int lastBuffer = 1; glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, lastBuffer++);` ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 So I need to FIRST create object (aka reserve it) with `glGenBuffers` and THEN I can use it with `glBindBuffer`, and if I just use "random name" it might, or it might not work, depending if that object is flagged with "unused". Right? (In summary: Just go with safe path: glGenBuffers -> glBindBuffer -> do something else)

Comment: @Danijel You can reserve a bunch of names at begin  of your application and manage them yourself when you need ta buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenGL 4.6 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) states in Section 6.1 states that `glBindBuffer` has to throw an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` exception when buffer does not point to a name previously reserved by `glGenBuffers`:

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if buffer is not zero or a name
>   returned from a previous call to GenBuffers, or if such a name has since been
>   deleted with DeleteBuffers.

The same information is stated in the [official docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml).

I'm not sure why docs.GL doesn't state that information. It might be that we are interpreting the sentence in a wrong way since it states that buffer is created. Technically, only the buffer name is created by the call to `glGenBuffers`, but the buffer object is created when the name gets bound for the first time.

Comment: You're right this is the difference in compare to OpenGL ES.

Comment: @Rabbid76: Interesting, didn't know that glBindBuffer behaves different in ES. But that might explain why docs.GL states wrong information.